# Installing BCML, "Encountered error while generating package metadata." (using Windows CMD)

Tags: python

This is a big issue because my brother wants to play botw modded but it's not working

i tried with "pip install bcml" but it always throws this error at me, also tried with pipx, didn't work.

it also puts in "Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error"

metadata below

```
  Running from numpy source directory.
  setup.py:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
    run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
  Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
  Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
  Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
  Cythonizing sources
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  blis_info:
    libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
  get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
  customize GnuFCompiler
  Could not locate executable g77
  Could not locate executable f77
  customize IntelVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable ifort
  Could not locate executable ifl
  customize AbsoftFCompiler
  Could not locate executable f90
  customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable DF
  customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable efl
  customize Gnu95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable gfortran
  Could not locate executable f95
  customize G95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable g95
  customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
  customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
  Could not locate executable efort
  Could not locate executable efc
  customize PGroupFlangCompiler
  Could not locate executable flang
  don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_info:
    libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_info:
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  accelerate_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0fp61toy\numpy_e478bd8b2a3444248cdb9210d9493653\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
      Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
      Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
      A better performance should be easily gained by switching
      Blas library.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
  blas_info:
    libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0fp61toy\numpy_e478bd8b2a3444248cdb9210d9493653\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
      the BLAS environment variable.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
  blas_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0fp61toy\numpy_e478bd8b2a3444248cdb9210d9493653\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
      the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
    NOT AVAILABLE

  non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_clapack_info:
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  flame_info:
    libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_info:
    libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0fp61toy\numpy_e478bd8b2a3444248cdb9210d9493653\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0fp61toy\numpy_e478bd8b2a3444248cdb9210d9493653\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
    FOUND:
      language = c
      define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

  C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z1g8008d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running dist_info
  running build_src
  build_src
  building py_modules sources
  creating build
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\distutils
  building library "npymath" sources
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z1g8008d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 157, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z1g8008d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 248, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z1g8008d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 499, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "setup.py", line 491, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0fp61toy\numpy_e478bd8b2a3444248cdb9210d9493653\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
      return old_setup(**new_attr)
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z1g8008d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z1g8008d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z1g8008d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z1g8008d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z1g8008d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\dist_info.py", line 31, in run
      egg_info.run()
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0fp61toy\numpy_e478bd8b2a3444248cdb9210d9493653\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 24, in run
      self.run_command("build_src")
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z1g8008d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z1g8008d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0fp61toy\numpy_e478bd8b2a3444248cdb9210d9493653\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 144, in run
      self.build_sources()
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0fp61toy\numpy_e478bd8b2a3444248cdb9210d9493653\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 155, in build_sources
      self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0fp61toy\numpy_e478bd8b2a3444248cdb9210d9493653\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 288, in build_library_sources
      sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0fp61toy\numpy_e478bd8b2a3444248cdb9210d9493653\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
      source = func(extension, build_dir)
    File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 650, in get_mathlib_info
      st = config_cmd.try_link('int main(void) { return 0;}')
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z1g8008d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 243, in try_link
      self._link(body, headers, include_dirs,
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0fp61toy\numpy_e478bd8b2a3444248cdb9210d9493653\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 161, in _link
      return self._wrap_method(old_config._link, lang,
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0fp61toy\numpy_e478bd8b2a3444248cdb9210d9493653\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 95, in _wrap_method
      ret = mth(*((self,)+args))
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z1g8008d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 137, in _link
      (src, obj) = self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0fp61toy\numpy_e478bd8b2a3444248cdb9210d9493653\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 104, in _compile
      src, obj = self._wrap_method(old_config._compile, lang,
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0fp61toy\numpy_e478bd8b2a3444248cdb9210d9493653\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 95, in _wrap_method
      ret = mth(*((self,)+args))
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z1g8008d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 132, in _compile
      self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z1g8008d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 401, in compile
      self.spawn(args)
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z1g8008d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 505, in spawn
      return super().spawn(cmd, env=env)
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0fp61toy\numpy_e478bd8b2a3444248cdb9210d9493653\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 90, in <lambda>
      m = lambda self, *args, **kw: func(self, *args, **kw)
  TypeError: CCompiler_spawn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'env'
  [end of output]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the python version that you are using. Try to install python 3.8 and that should work!

You can follow the instructions in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n76DOy-jbl4

Have a nice day!